# JS code to Autofill difference without any button and how to link that code to html. like "r1-c1=m1"

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<body>

<h2>Product Details</h2> 

<form Name="List" method="post" action="pprocess.php">

        <label>Product Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="Product_id" /><br />

        <label>Product Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Product_name" /><br />

        <label>Cost</label>
            <input type="text" name="Cost" id="c1"/><br />

        <label>Rate</label>
            <input type="text" name="Rate" id="r1"  /><br />

        <label>Profit</label>
            <input type="text" name="Prof" id="m1"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit"  value="Add Item">     
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: This is unclear, could you possibly add more information on what you mean, what you have tried, your result and an example of your expected result. Why is the PHP tag in this aswell? The question sounds like it may be about javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply a math calculation you can do it via HTML `onchange` event

```js
function getProfit(){
  var c1 =  document.querySelector('#c1').value;
  var r1 =  document.querySelector('#r1').value;
  if(r1 && c1){
    document.querySelector('#m1').value = r1-c1;
  }
}
getProfit();
```

```html
<form Name="List" method="post" action="pprocess.php">

        <label>Product Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="Product_id" value="101" /><br />

        <label>Product Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Product_name" value="Test" /><br />

        <label>Cost</label>
            <input onchange="getProfit()" type="text" name="Cost" id="c1" value="100" /><br />

        <label>Rate</label>
            <input onchange="getProfit()" type="text" name="Rate" id="r1" value="120"  /><br />

        <label>Profit</label>
            <input type="text" name="Prof" id="m1" value="0"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit"  value="Add Item">     
    </form>
```